# Highlighting the active anchor href via :target or jquery

Tags: jquery, css, anchor

On this page > http://clickbump.com/65/

When you click on one of the links in the table of contents "in this article" feature, it automatically scrolls the contents into view and uses a tiny jquery to move the toc widget adjacent to the current anchor point.

Ideally, I'd use the :target attribute in order to highlight the currently active section in the toc widget. However, I'm already using that for the anchors themselves.

Can jQuery do this?

Comment: Do you want to know how to achieve that? Or are you wanting something else? What exactly do you want?

Comment: I'm looking for a method, css or script, to highlight the currently active bookmark in the table of contents box

Comment: With pure CSS I don't think so since you already have a link with the ID of your bookmark, so you can't target another element since you'd need to duplicate IDs. But with jQuery it would be relatively easy.

Comment: Good point. I've updated my question to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a class when someone clicks the link pretty easily

```
$('.cb-toc li').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings('li').removeClass('active');
});
```

Here is [a working .jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hLeQy/) with the above

Comment: And also be sure to remove the newClass from the siblings. So...

$('cb-toc li').on('click', function(){
       $(this).addClass('newClass').siblings('li').removeClass('newClass');
});

Comment: I was just searching for that. Tried toggleClass to no avail. Thanks Jon +1 for that.

Comment: I'm adding the active class to the anchor rather than the li. Already have css for that.

Comment: I'm trying: $('.cb-toc a').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings('a').removeClass('active');})

Comment: ...but its not removing the class from the siblings for some reason

Comment: there aren't sibling a tags within the li element.  My example places the active class on the li which allows the .siblings to work.  You might need to adjust css to have your active class work

Answer (score 0):

Since you appear to be physically moving the TOC in the document to a position below the anchor, you would be able to do it with pure CSS:

```css
#bookmark2:target + .cb-toc a[href="#bookmark2"] {
  color: #444;
}
```

The problem with this is of course that you would have to add a selector for each anchor/link pair and since you are already using jQuery to manipulate the position of the TOC it would be better and cleaner to stick with the jQuery-based solution that Jon Harding proposed.